# How to tune parameters of SVM Rank?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel, svm, ranking

I am using [SVM Rank](http://svmlight.joachims.org/), which has multiple parameters, changing whom I am getting a variety of results. Is there some mechanism to tune and get the best parameters, as tuned according to the best results on validation set?

Below are the different parameters:

```
Learning Options:
     -c float    -> C: trade-off between training error
                    and margin (default 0.01)
     -p [1,2]    -> L-norm to use for slack variables. Use 1 for L1-norm,
                    use 2 for squared slacks. (default 1)
     -o [1,2]    -> Rescaling method to use for loss.
                    1: slack rescaling
                    2: margin rescaling
                    (default 2)
     -l [0..]    -> Loss function to use.
                    0: zero/one loss
                    ?: see below in application specific options
                    (default 1)
Optimization Options (see [2][5]):
     -w [0,..,9] -> choice of structural learning algorithm (default 3):
                    0: n-slack algorithm described in [2]
                    1: n-slack algorithm with shrinking heuristic
                    2: 1-slack algorithm (primal) described in [5]
                    3: 1-slack algorithm (dual) described in [5]
                    4: 1-slack algorithm (dual) with constraint cache [5]
                    9: custom algorithm in svm_struct_learn_custom.c
     -e float    -> epsilon: allow that tolerance for termination
                    criterion (default 0.001000)
     -k [1..]    -> number of new constraints to accumulate before
                    recomputing the QP solution (default 100)
                    (-w 0 and 1 only)
     -f [5..]    -> number of constraints to cache for each example
                    (default 5) (used with -w 4)
     -b [1..100] -> percentage of training set for which to refresh cache
                    when no epsilon violated constraint can be constructed
                    from current cache (default 100%) (used with -w 4)
SVM-light Options for Solving QP Subproblems (see [3]):
     -n [2..q]   -> number of new variables entering the working set
                    in each svm-light iteration (default n = q).
                    Set n < q to prevent zig-zagging.
     -m [5..]    -> size of svm-light cache for kernel evaluations in MB
                    (default 40) (used only for -w 1 with kernels)
     -h [5..]    -> number of svm-light iterations a variable needs to be
                    optimal before considered for shrinking (default 100)
     -# int      -> terminate svm-light QP subproblem optimization, if no
                    progress after this number of iterations.
                    (default 100000)
Kernel Options:
     -t int      -> type of kernel function:
                    0: linear (default)
                    1: polynomial (s a*b+c)^d
                    2: radial basis function exp(-gamma ||a-b||^2)
                    3: sigmoid tanh(s a*b + c)
                    4: user defined kernel from kernel.h
     -d int      -> parameter d in polynomial kernel
     -g float    -> parameter gamma in rbf kernel
     -s float    -> parameter s in sigmoid/poly kernel
     -r float    -> parameter c in sigmoid/poly kernel
     -u string   -> parameter of user defined kernel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as [grid search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization). I don't know if you're familiar with python and scikit-learn, but either way, I think [their description and examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) are very good and language agnostic.

Basically, you specify some values you're interested in for each parameter (or an interval from which to take random samples, see the randomized search) and then for each combination of settings, cross validation (usually [k fold cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29)) is used to compute how well the model does with those settings. The best performing combination is returned (scikit-learn can actually return a ranking of the combinations).

Note that this can take a long time. You should be rather certain of some parameters yourself, based on your problem. For example, for text classification, you should just pick the linear kernel, for other problems you'll probably want `rbf` etc. Don't just throw everything at the grid search, decide for as many parameters as you can using your knowledge of the algorithm and the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks @|V|ad. Can you please give the clarification of "for text classification, you should just pick the linear kernel"?

Comment: @BitManipulator - I mean, it's well known in the literature that for text classification, the instances are (almost) linearly separable in the high dimensions resulting from a bag of words model. So the linear kernel performs best, there's no point trying the others. Not trying multiple kernels means that you will only have to tune parameters for a single one, saving you a lot of time.